# What will happen to my RSS feeds on the blog after tI ransfer it from wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to transfer my blog from 'www.currentblog.wordpress.com' to 'www.currentblog.com'. 
In this case what will happen to my existing RSS feeds. Will they be automatically updated. I have not burnt my feeds using FeedBurner.

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually moving the content from the Wordpress server to your domain name then I think they'd have to change. You could alternatively just forward or redirect the domain to the current blog and don't bother with the hassle.